# Why no On The Road hat?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash, ios-app

I asked [`https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50539`](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50539) using the iOS app but didn't receive [the On The Road hat](//winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/on-the-road). Why not? (I edited the question within [the edit window](//meta.stackexchange.com/tags/grace-period/info) from a desktop computer. Perhaps that has something to do with it?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it hasn't gotten any upvotes yet. The hat is only awarded once it's positively scored.

[Why didn't (or did) I or some other user get a hat although the requirements were (or weren't) fulfilled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer/245123#245123)

Comment: Now it has an upvote and I got the hat.